# Best way to return "champion" that exists in a table in case the given query "championship" is not found

Tags: mysql, select, indexing

I have a very big table with strings.
Field "words":

```
- dog
- champion
- cat
- this is a cat
- pool
- champ
- boots
...
```

In my example, if a select query is looking for the given string "championship", it won't find it because this string is not in the table.
In that case, I want the query to return "champion" from the table, i.e. the longest string in the table that begins the given word "championship".
The possible match (if found) is the longest one in table between championship, or championshi, or championsh, or champions, ..., or cham, or cha, or ch, or C.

Question: I want to return longest string in table that starts a given string.
I need high speed. Is there a way to create index and query in order to have fast execution of queries?

Comment: look up 'lomgest common substring'

Comment: Than you for your commment, I already have searched but I haven't found the case of left susbtring, and I think that left matching can be a lot faster than substring anywhere in the word.

Answer (score 0):

You are a little vague with 'the longest string in the table that begins the given word "championship".'  Would "championing" count as a match?

Perhaps the following will help.  If you have an index on `words`, then the following will return the last word before the given word.  It should maximize the initial sequence of matches:

```
select word
from t
where words <= 'championship'
order by words desc
limit 1;
```

This isn't exactly what you are asking for, but it might work in practice.

EDIT:

If you are looking for an exact match, then the following should use an index on words effectively and return what you want:

```
select word
from t
where word in ('championship', 'championshi', 'championsh', 'champions', 'champion',
               'champio', 'champi', 'champ', 'cham', 'cha', 'ch', 'c')
order by word desc
limit 1;
```

It is a bit brute force, but it should have the property of using the index to speed up the query.

Comment: Sorry if it is a little vague. championing doesn't count as a match. The possible match if found is the longest one found if it exists in table between championship, or championshi, or championsh, or champions, ..., or cham, or cha, or ch or c.
I'm testing your solution concerning speed, thank you for your suggestion.

Comment: This solution doesn't work : if championr is in the table, the query would return it : "championr"<"championship'...

Answer (score 0):

Here's one query that will return the specified result:

```
SELECT t.mycol
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE 'championship' LIKE CONCAT(t.mycol,'%')
 ORDER
    BY LENGTH(t.mycol) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

This query can't do a index range scan, it's going to have to be full scan, but it may be able to use an index to satisfy the query.

If you can restrict the search to a finite number of leading letters that need to match to be considered a "hit", you could include another predicate. For example, to match at least 4 characters:

```
SELECT t.mycol
  FROM mytable t 
 WHERE 'championship' LIKE CONCAT(t.mycol,'%')
   AND t.mycol LIKE 'cham%'
 ORDER
    BY LENGTH(t.mycol) DESC
 LIMIT 1
```

--or--

```
  AND t.mycol >= 'cham' 
  AND t.mycol <  'chan'
```

Comment: Thank you, it works but the problem is the full scan as you mentioned it, it is too slow for my need. I think there is a faster solution, maybe I'm wrong :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this article:

http://blog.fatalmind.com/2010/09/29/finding-the-best-match-with-a-top-n-query/

It explains the solution from this SO question:

[How to use index efficienty in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778319/how-to-use-index-efficienty-in-mysql-query)

The solution pattern looks like this:

```
select words
  from (
        select words
          from yourtable
         where words <= 'championship'
         order by words desc
         limit 1
       ) tmp
 where 'championship' like concat (words, '%')
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it seems it doesn't work in my case.
Suppose f I have "championride" in yourtable, the part between ( ) selects championride ("champion" < "championride"<"championship), so the complete query won't match "champion" and will return nothing.

Comment: @Kate true. The "no overlap" prerequisite mentioned in my article is not fulfilled in your case. I'll see if I can come up with another solution.

Comment: Thank you, I'm wondering if I should use trie tree, but mysql doesn't seem to offer this structure option.