# How to tune a range / interval query in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a table `A` with intervals `(COL1, COL2)`:

```
CREATE TABLE A (
  COL1 NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
  COL2 NUMBER(15) NOT NULL,
  VAL1 ...,
  VAL2 ...
);
ALTER TABLE A ADD CONSTRAINT COL1_BEFORE_COL2 CHECK (COL1 <= COL2);
```

The intervals are guaranteed to be "exclusive", i.e. they will never overlap. In other words, this query yields no rows:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT
    LEAD(COL1, 1) OVER (ORDER BY COL1) NEXT,
    COL2
  FROM A
)
WHERE COL2 >= NEXT;
```

There is currently an index on `(COL1, COL2)`. Now, my query is the following:

```
SELECT /*+FIRST_ROWS(1)*/ *
FROM A
WHERE :some_value BETWEEN COL1 AND COL2
AND ROWNUM = 1
```

This performs well (less than a ms for millions of records in `A`) for low values of `:some_value`, because they're very selective on the index. But it performs quite badly (almost a second) for high values of `:some_value` because of a lower selectivity of the access predicate.

The execution plan seems good to me. As the existing index already fully covers the predicate, I get the expected `INDEX RANGE SCAN`:

```
------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                    | Name | E-Rows |
------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT             |      |        |
|*  1 |  COUNT STOPKEY               |      |        |
|   2 |   TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| A    |      1 |
|*  3 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN          | A_PK |        |
------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter(ROWNUM=1)
   3 - access("VAL2">=:some_value AND "VAL1"<=:some_value)
       filter("VAL2">=:some_value)
```

In `3`, it becomes obvious that the access predicate is selective only for low values of `:some_value` whereas for higher values, the filter operation "kicks in" on the index.

Is there any way to generally improve this query to be fast regardless of the value of `:some_value`? I can completely redesign the table if further normalisation is needed.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your attempt is good, but misses a few crucial issues.

Let's start slowly. I'm assuming an index on `COL1` and I actually don't mind if `COL2` is included there as well.

Due to the constraints you have on your data (especially non-overlapping) you actually just want the row *before* the row where `COL1` is `<=` some value....[--take a break--] it you order by `COL1`

This is a [classic Top-N query](http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/partial-results/top-n-queries?dbtype=oracle):

```
select *
  FROM ( select *
          from A
         where col1 <= :some_value
         order by col1 desc
       )
 where rownum <= 1;
```

Please note that you **must** use `ORDER BY` to get a definite sort order. As `WHERE` is applied after `ORDER BY` you must now also wrap the top-n filter in an outer query.

That's almost done, the only reason why we actually need to filter on `COL2` too is to filter out records that don't fall into the range at all. E.g. if some_value is 5 and you are having this data:

```
  COL1 | COL2
     1 |  2
     3 |  4   <-- you get this row 
     6 | 10
```

This row would be correct as result, if `COL2` would be 5, but unfortunately, in this case the correct result of your query is [empty set]. That's the only reason we need to filter for `COL2` like this:

```
select *
  FROM ( select *
           FROM ( select *
                    from A
                   where col1 <= :some_value
                   order by col1 desc
                )
          where rownum <= 1
        )
  WHERE col2 >= :some_value;
```

Your approach had several problems:

- missing `ORDER BY` - dangerous in connection with `rownum` filter!
- applying the Top-N clause (`rownum` filter) too early. What if there is **no** result? Database reads index until the end, the `rownum` (STOPKEY) never kicks in.
- An optimizer glitch. With the `between` predicate, my 11g installation doesn't come to the idea to read the index in descending order, so it was actually reading it from the beginning (0) upwards until it found a `COL2` value that matched --OR-- the `COL1` run out of the range.

.

```
COL1 | COL2
   1 |  2   ^
   3 |  4   |      (2) go up until first match.
            +----- your intention was to start here
   6 | 10
```

What was actually happening was:

```
  COL1 | COL2
     1 |  2   +----- start at the beginning of the index
     3 |  4   |      Go down until first match.      
              V
     6 | 10
```

Look at the execution plan of my query:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                       | Name   | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                |        |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                           |        |     1 |    26 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   COUNT STOPKEY                 |        |       |       |            |          |
|   3 |    VIEW                         |        |     2 |    52 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|   4 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | A      | 50000 |   585K|     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  5 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN DESCENDING| SIMPLE |     2 |       |     3   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Note the `INDEX RANGE SCAN **DESCENDING**`.

Finally, why didn't I include `COL2` in the index? It's a single row-top-n query. You can save at most a single table access (irrespective of what the Rows estimation above says!) If you expect to find a row in most cases, you'll need to go to the table anyways for the other columns (probably) so you would not save ANYTHING, just consume space. Including the `COL2` will only improve performance if you query doesn't return anything at all!

Related:

- [How to use index efficienty in mysql query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778319/how-to-use-index-efficienty-in-mysql-query)
   I answered a very similar question about this years ago. Same solution.
- [Use The Index, Lukas!](http://use-the-index-luke.com)

Comment: +1 for renaming your brand to "use the index Lukas". That's tailor-made support :-). I had also tested the doubly-nested `ROWNUM` filtering, but I'll test again. There had been quite a few analysis steps. Maybe, I did something wrong on the way... The key thing here might actually be leaving `COL2` out of the index

Comment: @LukasEder if you have can show your attempts we can see to find the problem. `COL2` should not be an issue.

Comment: While this query seems to perform just as well as the accepted answer, I'm a bit concerned about the E-Rows value being quite off in my query's actual plan. [Thomas Köhne's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22250285/521799) seems to have a more optimal plan with a correct E-Rows value of 1 throughout the query (unless I'm missing something). Besides, it is very readable with respect to the mutual exclusivity of the queried intervals. But thanks anyway! It is always important to be reminded of the Oracle CBO's capability to leverage `ROWNUM` semantics!

Answer (score 4):

I think, because the ranges do not intersect, you can define col1 as primary key and execute the query like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM    a
       JOIN
          (SELECT MAX (col1) AS col1
             FROM a
            WHERE col1 <= :somevalue) b
       ON a.col1 = b.col1;
```

If there are gaps between the ranges you wil have to add:

```
Where col2 >= :somevalue
```

as last line.

Execution Plan:

```
SELECT STATEMENT  
 NESTED LOOPS  
  VIEW  
   SORT AGGREGATE 
    FIRST ROW  
     INDEX RANGE SCAN (MIN/MAX) PKU1
  TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX A
   INDEX UNIQUE SCAN PKU1
```

Comment: That's quite a clever solution. I wonder what @MarkusWinand thinks about this...?

Comment: Smart solution, thought of that myself. But I think that it is unlikely to outperform @MarkusWinand's one (or they both show the same results). Can you post the plan to compare? There should be `INDEX RANGE SCAN` and `INDEX UNIQUE SCAN` I guess.

Comment: I have added the execution plan in my post.

Comment: That's indeed a very cunning solution. I can reproduce this plan. Given the knowledge about ranges being mutually exclusive, this solution seems optimal and very readable. Thanks!

Comment: @LukasEder As you can see from the execution plan, it is less efficient due to double index access (although it is very likely cached). Further, this solution doesn't "scale" in that sense that it gets very complex if would have multiple columns you need to order by/max() (which is probably never the case in when you have [from:to]. Nevertheless, I'd suggest my pattern for the general case. But if you don't like it, I cant change that ;) Note: SQL Server can automatically transform this query, to my query during optimization ;)

Comment: @MarkusWinand: You're right, of course, in general :-) I hadn't thought about double vs. single index access. Perhaps, though, the fact that our data setup actually leads to the same single row being returned from both range and unique scans leads to the double access being negligible? Interesting thing about SQL Server. Can Oracle 12c do it as well, now that we have support for `OFFSET .. FETCH`?

Comment: @LukasEder As I said "although it is very likely cached". Physical IO won't suffer a lot, but logical IO will be twice as high as needed because it needs to Travers the tree twice.It's mostly about CPU and locking. Cutting CPU usage by half is usually a good thing ;) Especially if the DB you are using is changed on that basis...

Comment: @MarkusWinand: OK, I'm starting to believe that you are right ;-)

Comment: Thats ok for me. If you like to tweak things a little bit, here and there and love to analyse executions plans, Markus Solutions sure works best.
Both statements are fast enough, and i would prefere the more simple one, until i have an real CPU issue here. Not everything is about performance.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe changing this heap table to IOT table would give better performance.

Comment: Not in my case. The existing index fully covers the predicate, so I'm good with an INDEX RANGE SCAN... I guess I should update my question with that info

Comment: Hmm, In your place I would try to use hash partitioned global indexes.

Comment: Hmm, I've thought about partitioning before, but not about hash partitioning. Can you show some details about how (and why) this can be optimised with hash partitioning?

Answer (score -1):

I didn't generate sample data to test this but you might want to give it a try.

```
ALTER TABLE A ADD COL3 NUMBER(15);

UPDATE A SET COL3 = COL2 - COL1;
```

Create index on COL3.

```
SELECT /*+FIRST_ROWS(1)*/ *
FROM A
WHERE :some_value < COL3
AND ROWNUM = 1;
```

Comment: That won't return the correct result. Example: `:some_value = 5`, `COL1 = 4`, `COL2 = 6`, `(:some_value BETWEEN COL1 AND COL2) IS TRUE`, `COL3 = 2`, `(:some_value < COL3) IS FALSE`