# Indexing a LEFT operation in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, indexing

I have a database table of E.164 calling codes (e.g. `1` for USA/Canada, `44` for the United Kingdom, etc). Here's the table design:

```
CREATE TABLE CountryCosts (
    CallingCode varchar(5) PK NOT NULL
    IsFree      bit           NOT NULL
)
```

I have a scalar function which accepts a full phone number and indicates if any country-code in the table matches the number (simply by checking if the number begins with any `CountryCode` in the table) and indiciates if `IsFree` is true or not.

```sql
SELECT
    TOP 1
    CallingCode,
    GratisPermitted
FROM
    CountryCosts
WHERE
    GratisPermitted = 1
    AND
    LEFT( @recipient, LEN( CallingCode ) ) = CallingCode
```

(Variations exist, including using `SELECT COUNT(1)` inside an `SELECT CASE WHEN EXISTS` and using `@recipient LIKE CONCAT( CallingCode, '%' )` as the predicate)

The Actual Execution Plan reports the main expense is a Clustered Index Scan of the Clustered PK index.

I want to know if there's any way I can improve the performance by adding another index, is there any index that works on `varchar` columns that SQL Server would use to optimize the `LEFT` predicate?

Comment: A PK comprising both code & isfree seems logical and some kind of padding scheme to remove the LEN() call in the WHERE clause

Comment: I don't know much about this scheme but presumably it ensures that there is no ambiguity? e.g. Only USA/Canada can start with `'1'` and there is no code starting with `'123'` for example? In which case you could seek into the `TOP 1 CallingCode ... <= @recipient ORDER BY CallingCode DESC` and then validate just that one row to see if it matched.

Comment: @MartinSmith correct, country-codes with the same initial digits are the same length, so `12` is not a country-code because `1` belongs to the USA/Canada. `44` is the UK, but `4` by itself is not a code, similarly `443` is not a code.

Comment: @MartinSmith also, that's a genius suggestion! I'll try it out!

Comment: You must have no performances problem. I mean, you already use an index. LEFT command, will use index. By the way, which are your indexes?
Have you performances problem? If yes, with so few records, what I suggest, if possible and safe in your situation, is to read this table " WITH(NOLOCK) "
If it is a stressed table, and you are on SQL 2014, you can also put it in memory.

Comment: @MartinSmith Yes, is's a variation of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3778319/how-to-use-index-efficienty-in-mysql-query the there explained works in any database.

Comment: How many rows are in the table?

Comment: That would explain why the index is not used. The table is too small.

Comment: @danb - The index *can't* be used as the query is not sargable. Even for very small tables that fit on a single page and don't have a root page an index [can still be of benefit - at least in theory](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/68793/3690).